# How do these patterns differ?

Tags: javascript

How does this:

```
var obj = obj || {};

obj.Something = (function() {

    function Something() {

    };

    Something.prototype.someMethod = function() {

    };

    return Something;

})();
```

differ from this:

```
obj.Something = function() {

};

obj.Something.prototype = {

};
```

How do the patterns differ?
When would I use one over the other?

Comment: Insist on a proper answer from your teacher.

Comment: @BartKiers I can't, I am not at college and I will not see him for a week!

Comment: Your teacher actually writes `class Something` on coffescript to js compiler and decides that it's the best alternative ever

Comment: If your question was 'what are the differences, and disadvantages, of these two approaches' then I'd consider it an on-topic question; but the phrasing is, essentially, asking us to second-guess your teacher. Which we can't do. Please: rephrase your question's title.

Comment: @user2251919 And you can not email the professor? Seems odd a computer prof would not have an email. And the profs answer deals with being able to have "private" scope.

Comment: @DavidThomas you cannot second guess of course you can't, but I know that teachers don't always know all that they say they do, and I don't want to preach what he says unless what he says is solid.

Comment: @user2251919 - Please see http://well-spun.co.uk/portfolio/technologies/javascript/oop.php for my take on OOD in Javascript.

Comment: @epascarello Yes i can email him, but I won't get an answer probably until tomorow night, I don't want to waste time waiting for an answer when I could be learning.

Comment: @EdHeal, i'm getting a 500 server error on that link.

Comment: @user2251919: This question as it currently is asked is not very constructive in my opinion. The way it currently is phrased is that you are told to do one thing but don't agree. If you are still learning you should assume that the person teaching you has their reasons. However, being inquisitive is great and if you have a genuine question to what is different between 2 approaches than that is what the question should focus on instead of sounding like a "Who is right?" question which is not very constructive as the "right" may be depending on circumstances not known to us.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, it was an inquisitive question not a argumentative one, just was asked wrong!

Comment: @user2251919, don't forget to update the questions at the bottom as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason why you would use the way your teacher recommends is that you may define other variables and functions that wouldn't be exposed in the global scope.

For example :

```
obj.Something = (function() {
    var sum = 0;
    function Something() {
    };
    Something.increment = function(){ sum++ };
    Something.getSum = function(){ return sum };    
    return Something;
})();
```

Here the `sum` isn't public and doesn't pollute the global namespace.

Other than that, both patterns are pretty similar. But it's a good idea to get accustomed to the [IIFE pattern](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) especially when, as you do, you try to know why it's useful and not just apply it.

Comment: That, and it allows him to skip the `new` keyword.

Comment: And the reverse, the local variables can't be touched by other code. Plus, you can use (for example) `function($, window, undefined) {})(jQuery, window)` to "lock in" certain globals or values that you wish to also remain untampered-with.

Comment: Yep that what came to my mind too. Perhaps it's like a code best practices for class, since extending it is very easier if its written that way

Comment: @alex23 if one declares `var sum = 0` at the same level as the outer code, it is a global variable. This is very basic stuff.

Comment: @alex23 If you add other variables (including functions) you need, other than the ones that you expose, you must define them somewhere.

Comment: @alex23 Then it isn't very private, is it? It can still be monkeyed with by `obj.sum`.

Comment: So unless I want private variables that are inside the functions closure, this pattern is basically the same as doing it the way I have shown?

Comment: Yes, but you rarely work without private variables, that's why it's a good idea to use it. And yes, your pattern is sensible too.

Comment: Also imagine what will happen if you need a singleton?

Comment: Also the first method allows the class to be renamed easily in one step, rather than having to search through the code for every instance of `obj.Something`.

Comment: @alex23 I'm sure I follow. That's enough for me. It is okay with me for you to have your doubts. :)

Comment: @alex23, you seem to be misunderstanding me. If you start with `obj.Something` and need it renamed such that you can call `new obj.Foo()`, you only have to change `obj.Something = (function...` to `obj.Foo = (function...`, the internal code can continue to use `function Something` without any issues. This makes the code ***significantly more maintainable***.

Comment: @dystroy the question got closed, but this answers what I was asking very justifiably, thank you for your time and answer.

Comment: @alex23, no, find & replace is a terrible way to make changes. It makes it really easy to change the wrong thing, or miss changing the right thing. Part of what makes code more maintainable is the ability to change it without needing to worry whether the changes you're making are going to negatively impact the rest of the code base.

Comment: @zzzzBov I have used find and replace before as a shortcut and have totally messed stuff up you think wouldn't get changed but did!

Answer (score 1):

I think he is modeling more after an OOP approach. His syntax resembles a class definition, which may make it more "usable" according to his words

Answer (score 1):

In his example, he almost did a closure. You should read about that. If it had any variable in the context of the self-called function there, you'd have a closure.

Also, notice that in your teacher's example, something has a function on its prototype. In your example, you erased Something's prototype by replacing it with an empty one.

Comment: [Closure in Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)), the concept, not the language.

Comment: @Susanoh13 indeed. Thanks, I forgot to mention that.